# List implementation ontop of SQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, sqlite

I need to implement a list abstraction on top of a SQL DB. This list abstraction needs to support append, remove and insert operations.

My plan is to implement a key-value table, where the key contains sort/order-information and value contains the list values. To append elements to the top I just need to create a key that orders/sorts above the previous top. To insert a element I just need to create a key that orders/sorts between the two entries at insert position. With such a scheme I don't need to rebalance table afer I insert a element in the middle.

One possible naive implementation is to use fractional numbers for keys. To insert a value between two elements I just calculate the average of the keys for the two elements and uses this as key for the inserted value. Most DB's have finit precision for numbers. To overcome this we can convert the number to string and use various arbitrary precision libs to calculate average. With this scheme the key grows by 1 digit pr insert. See example implementation below

```
function between(prev_key:number,next_key:number):number {
  var insert_key = (prev_key + next_key) / 2.0;
  assert(insert_key > prev_key && insert_key < next_key);
  return insert_key;
}
```

Growing the key by 1 digit for every row inserted is not very scalable. I have experimented with different key schemes and "between" implementations. But most/all have problems with fast growing keys-lengths on insert. My gut is telling me there is a optimal strategy for this, but the solution is eluding me.

Note I use number as key-type in this example, but key can be string or any other type as long as I'm able to generate a between key and order correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well one obvious optimisation you can make for length is when you take the average try rounding it and seeing if it still works. ie when average 1 and 1.5 you get 1.25. Round that to 1.3 and that still works. Key doesn't grow. NExt step doing 1.5 and 1.3 you'll get 1.4. Or 1 and 1.3 you get 1.15 and rounding it you'd get the acceptable 1.2. Its only when you are looking between 1.2 and 1.3 that you'd need the key to actually grow in length. Its probably still not perfect but it is at least better then growing the key by 1 digit each time...

Comment: This will reduce the problem but not fix it as far as I can see. The key size complexity will still be O(N) with regards to list size, i.e. 1M rows will generate key lengths in the 100k range. I'm looking for somthing close to a O(log N) solution to key size :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a single value to index your values, you are implementing a list on top of what is essentially an array.

It would be easier to actually use a data structure that resembles a list, i.e., where each entry has pointers to the next and previous node. In SQL, pointers are foreign keys. In an in-memory list, the identity of a node would be its address, which is random, so in SQL, you can simply use an autoincrementing PK:

```
CREATE TABLE List (
    ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Prev INTEGER REFERENCES List,
    Next INTEGER REFERENCES List,
    Value
);
```

To insert or remove, you have to adjust the `Prev`/`Next` values in the node itself and its neighbouring nodes.

To iterate through the list, you have to follow the `Next` pointers, which requires a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE iteration AS (
  SELECT Value, Next
  FROM List
  WHERE ID = 0    -- or Prev IS NULL, or however you identify the first entry

  UNION ALL

  SELECT Value, Next
  FROM List
  JOIN iteration ON List.ID = iteration.Next
)
SELECT Value FROM iteration;
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not think about applying a recursive CTE to this problem, but you are right, this will solve my problem. And the performance should be OK with a primary key index on ID.

Comment: I'm still wondering if there is a way to generate keys in such a way that my original approch would work for big lists. I will leave this thread open a day or two and see if I get any interesting input. But consider you answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

After a night of sleep I think I have found a way to generate efficient keys for the algorithmic problem stated in the initial post.

The trick is to reserve a range of values once you need to extend the key length on insert. So instead of adding one digit like we do when averaging, we "reserve" N digits. In this reserved range we can count up by one for every insert where key is bigger than previous. This gives us O(log n) key length within reserved range. If we need to go down we will have no room and need to expand again. But the second trick is to reverse the reserved range for every expand. So on the next reserved range we start from the top and count down.

Preliminary testing show that this structure generates very compact keys for both random inserts and multiple inserts at same position in list and head. However, I think it is possible to make the key size grow if you "attack" this structure with just the right insert pattern. So recursive CTE is probably the safer approach.

I can elaborate more later if requested